# I can no longer access quests in Candy Crush?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

I can no longer access Candy Crush Quests with Airplane Mode turned on and Facebook off from my iPad mini.

Why is this? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Candy Crush, along with many other games, get data such as quest objectives online. The only way to get the quests is to turn off airplane mode and connect to a network.